# Symfony 4 with ioncube in the controllers

Tags: symfony, ioncube

I'm trying to obfuscate only the Controllers with Ioncube, but I see that the routing system is not working properly(My route system are with annotated)

Also in the same ioncube not to obfuscate the comments in the following way

```
ioncube_encoder.sh -71 myfile.php -o /symfony/myfile.php --no-doc-comments
```

Here is a screenshot of the error
[image]

I also don't know how to modify that call to the route with a listener

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask what the reason is to obfuscating PHP? If it is down to stack traces and these error pages being shown to users then you should consider looking in to how the production environments should be setup.

Comment: The reason is simple: I've been working on a project for 4 months, which has cost me a lot of time and a lot of programming time. So the truth is, I'd like to protect the controllers even if it's just that. Because that is why it is ioncube to protect the code from easy modification.

Comment: Did you solve it? I think using the `--no-doc` causes to remove the annotation so that the router may not find it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blog.ioncube.com/2019/09/10/using-symfony-with-ioncube-encoder/) can help you